# C# mongoDB driver, problem with Limit() method

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I use c# MongoDB driver( IAggregateFluent Aggregate() ) in aggregation I use Limit() method after Group() and Project() stages , but amount of results that i receive every time is different (for example first time there's 20 results , next time there's 21 )  , what may be the problem and maybe there's better way to solve this problem ?

P.s
Swap stages in aggregation is not an option .

```
var a = objectCollection.Aggregate(new AggregateOptions() { AllowDiscUse = true})
.Group( some group parameters )
.Project()
.Match(my filters)
.Limit(1000)
.....
```

I found that Limit() after Group() and Match may work randomly.

Comment: And you're sure your data isn't changing and therefore altering the number of documents satisfying your filters, right?

Comment: Yes, i have static static db .

Comment: it's unlikely that db is static, just check the size of collection each time